# Getting href from parent anchor HtmlUnit

Tags: java, htmlunit

What I am trying to do is to use HtmlUnit to get the href from the parent anchor of a span. Here is what I mean.

```
  <a href="http://link.com/serv?id=jibberish&type=dynamic/changeseachvisit"><span>Some Unique Text</span></a>
```

There is no id or name associated with either the  or the  tags, so going by this example, how would you find that link in a sea of others like it without ids or names?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you use the link as a mean to identify it ?

Comment: Yes, you could, however this link has query string parameters attached to it and they are dynamic (change each time you visit the site and also based on who the visitor is

Comment: I don't know htmlunit, or what the api looks like, but I imagine you can traverse the DOM either directly in js or via a java api, so there must be a "getParent()" method

Comment: Yes, there is a getParent method, however, I cannot seem to get down to that span either, based on the innertext alone.

Comment: If you know the xpath and it's static, use that (assuming htmlunit understands xpaths). Else you'll have to iterate through the DOM searching for your unique text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the XPATH `//span[contains(.,'Transcript')]/parent::a/@href`

(non tested, but XPATH is definitely the way to go)

Comment: no, definitely not... You can use XPATH with HTMLUnit. I've used it a lot and XPath was my preferred method. In HTMLUnit [Getting Started](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html), you have a paragraph named 'Finding a specific element' which state : "XPath is the suggested way for more complex searches"

Comment: I am new to XPATH, I tried this.... page.getByXPath("//span/contains(.,'Transcript')/parent::a[@href]").get(0).toString() ... There are numerous errors like "unknown  nodetype: contains"

Comment: because it's a XPath String method, and not a node name... My XPath wasn't syntactically correct
try `//span[contains(.,'Transcript')]/parent::a/@href`

Comment: Could you explain your first statement? (xpath string method not a node name?). even with the new xpath statement i am getting an error with: page.getByXPath("//span[contains(.,'Transcript')]/parent::a/@href").get(0).toString()

Comment: I've tested on this page and `//span[contains(.,'Transcript')]` should work (at least)...
`//span` selects all the span node that contains the text 'Transcript'. `[]` are for conditional expression to narrow the result-set and `contains` return true or false for the context node it gets in params (here, it's the '.', ie the current node). Then the `parent::` axis is selected with tag 'a' as a filter, then it selects the href attribute. What I wanted to state before is that `//span/contains(...` doesn't mean anything as contains is a method, not a node type

Comment: you can test XPaths directly in Chrome Browser, or via the XPather extension for Firefox

Comment: ok, thank you.. using what I posted in my previous comment, the string equals DomAttr[name=href value=http://mylink.com]   ... How can i get ONLY the link?

Comment: `//span[contains(.,'Transcript')]/parent::a/@href/text()` should give you the link or `getNodeValue()` on your `DomAttr` object

Comment: the text() part didnt work out but the DomAttr getNodeValue did. Thanks!